# PHP MYSQL - $_GET and Query Issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page which contains a table. The 'change_id' field contains hyperlinks which direct the user to a different page with an overview of that change_id's details.

```
'<td><a href="home2.php?changeid=' . $row['change_id'] . '">' . $row['change_id'] . '</a></td>';
```

Now, just to test that the change_id is being received on the home2.php page, I used the following code:

```
<?php 
include 'config.php';
$change_id=$_GET['change_id'];
print_r($_GET);
?>
```

This test successfully displayed the correct change id's:

> Array ( [changeid] => 1006 )

Now, when I go to query the SQL Database using the change_id it doesn't work as desired.

```
<?php 
include 'config.php';
$change_id=$_GET['change_id'];
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM `change_request_tbl` WHERE `change_id` = $change_id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);

echo  "<fieldset><legend><strong>New Requests:</legend></strong>
<table border=4 bordercolor=black class=table>
<tr>
<th>Change ID:</th>
<th>Customer Name:</th>
<th>Change Requestor:</th>
<th>Date CR raised:</th>
<th>CPM/Ticket:</th>
<th>Out of Hours:</th>
<th>Change Category:</th>
</tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['change_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['customer_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['change_requestor'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['date_cr_raised'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['cpm_ticket'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['out_of_hours'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['category_of_change'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}  
echo "</table></fieldset><br><br><br>";
?>
```

The table are headers are shown without any data. Any ideas on how to fix? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your change_id an int in the table?

Comment: Auto Incremented INT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `$change_id` to `$_GET['change_id']`

However you are passing `$_GET` the parameter name of `changeid`

If you change

`$change_id = $_GET['change_id'];`

To

`$change_id = $_GET['changeid'];`

It should work as expected :)

Comment: its working now without the '_'. Why is this the case?

Comment: Because as far as PHP is concerned they are two different variables/parameters. Make sure you keep an eye on the CaSe and any symbols you use in PHP :)